# Can't retrieve data using ajax load function to retrieve MySQL data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I can retrieve information from a webpage not associated with a database, but when I try to use it with a database, that's when the problems begin.

I have two containers. The first container has a list of names and the second container will display the information for the selected name (from the first container). Ideally, the information will be pulled from the requested MySQL database table by the `id` for the name clicked. The id for the name in the database is referred to as the `$pmid` in PHP code. `newmessageData.php` is the page where the data is being pulled from.

I'm using hyperlinks because I can see the respective id's of the names as I hover over them, but if anyone suggests anything else, like buttons, I'll try it.

I'm new to ajax and I appreciate any suggestions or advice.

Here is my code:

`Containers.php`
PHP code:

```
  <?php
  //Connected to database and retrieved information.
  //Created table variable
  $table .= '
             <tr>
                <td><a id="link" href="newmessageData.php?pmid='.$pmid.'">'.$name.'</a></td>
             </tr>';    

?>
```

`Containers.php` HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="container">
    <table>
    <tr><?php echo $table; ?></tr>  <!-- Echoed $table here -->
    </table>        
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="ajax.js"></script>
        <script> <!--To prevent link from redirecting-->
            $("a").click(function() {
                return false;
            });
        </script>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div id="content"></div>    
    </div>
</div>
```

`ajax.js` file:

```
$('#link').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'newmessageData.php?pmid=<?php echo $pmid; ?>',
        success: function(data){
            $('#content').html(data);
            e.preventDefault(); // stop the browser from following the link
        }       
    }); 
});
```

`newmessageData.php` PHP code:
Sorry if anything is missing. Might have cleaned it up too much.

```
<?php
//Connect db and retrieve information
//Initial variables
$pmid = "";
$info= "";
// Make sure the _GET username is set, and sanitize it
if(isset($_GET["pmid"])){
    $pmid = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9]#i', '', $_GET['pmid']);
} 
// Get list of parent pm's not deleted
$sql = "SELECT * FROM pm WHERE id='$pmid'";
$query = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
$statusnumrows = mysqli_num_rows($query);
// Gather data about parent pm's
if($statusnumrows > 0){
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        $pmid = $row["id"];
        //textarea naming
        $rt = 'replytext_'.$pmid;
        //button naming
        $rb = 'replyBtn_'.$pmid;
        $receiver = $row["receiver"];
        $name= $row["name"];
        $subject = $row["subject"];
        $message = $row["message"];
        $time = $row["senttime"];
        $rread = $row["rread"];
        $sread = $row["sread"];

        // Start to build our list of parent pm's
        $info.= '<div class="container" id="'.$wrap.'" style="margin-top: 20px; border-radius: 7px; background: #ffffff; border: 2px solid #CCC; padding: 20px;">';
        $info.= '<div class="pm_header">'.$subject.'<br /><br />';
        // Add button for mark as read
        $info .= '<button onclick="markRead(\''.$pmid.'\',\''.$name.'\')">Mark As Read</button>';
        $info.= '<div id="'.$pmid2.'">';//start expanding area
        $info.= '<div id="pm_post" class="pm_post"><label>From:</label>&nbsp; '.$name.' <br /><label>Date:</label>&nbsp; '.$time.'<br /><label>Message:</label><br />'.$message.'</div><br />';

            $info.= '</div>';
    }
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
<script src="js/custom_ajax.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="info" id="info">
            <?php echo $info; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br /><br />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What message do you get in your console when you use `console.log(data)` inside the success function?

Comment: Not getting anything, actually. I looked at the Network tab and when I clicked any of the names, no activity.

Comment: What does your `newmessageData.php` look like? What does it output?

Comment: The `newmessageData.php` is a page that works perfectly when a link is normally clicked and re-directed to it. It gets the `$pmid` from the url and displays the requested information. I'll add it to the question, above.

Comment: Remove the prevent link from redirecting script and try

Comment: You need to isolate this down more. Does click code do anything? Does ajax request succeed? Some basic troubleshooting is needed to narrow down where your problem lies

Comment: Is your first code in a loop? If it is, change `id="link"` to `class="link"` since id's should be unique per element. Another thing, if you add a `console.log("hello world");` before your ajax call, does it get printed, since you have a `return false;` in all links on the page

Comment: `e.preventDefault();` should be right after `$("#link").click(function(e) { e.preventDefault(); // ajax code })`, not in your ajax callback

Comment: Without that script, when the name is clicked, it will re-direct to the page where the information is being pulled. My goal is to display the requested information in container 2, without re-direct. @ABUdhay

Comment: You need to wrap all your jQuery listeners in `$(function(){ $(...).click(...)  })` or they might get executed before jQuery is fully loaded...

Comment: Your url is correct?any xhr is posting in network tab?? Try adding which method your ajax has like post/get

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I added `console.log("hello world");` before the ajax call. It looked like this: `$('#link').click(function(){
 console.log("hello world");
 $.ajax({`. Nothing worked.

Comment: @ABUdhay Yes, the url is correct.

Comment: That's because you have disabled all links with your `$("a").click(....)`. Remove it and use `e.preventDefault()` correctly instead.

Comment: You need to see parameters on the URL? Why not leave the link as `<a href="#" data-id="{the_id}" class="{some_class}">{item}</a>` and then get parameters and execute the call by JS?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I have added the `newmessageData.php` code. I'll remove the script disabling the links now.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Thanks for your patience! I removed the script. Now the page just re-directs when clicked. No 'hello world' anywhere.

Comment: @ReynierPM do you know of any working examples to refer to? Thanks for the idea!

Comment: @Millica I am not following on your scripts/flow since I am seeing you output a whole HTML rather than `$info` at `newmessageData.php`, why is that? Any way take a look to [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39318136/force-page-refresh-on-redirect) from my authority maybe it points you on the right path

Comment: That's a good point. I should do that (output only $info). It's all new to me. And thanks for the link! I'll check it out! @ReynierPM